# Qual o significado dessa linha em Java?

Tags: java

Não entendi a seguinte linha do código abaixo:

```
ret += this.elem[i]+(i!=this.ultimo?", ":"");
```

Qual o significado desses operadores `i!` , `?` e `:`

```
{
    String ret = "{";

    for (int i=0; i<=this.ultimo; i++)
        ret += this.elem[i]+(i!=this.ultimo?", ":"");

    return ret+"}";
}
```

Comment: Não é i! E sim !=, Ali na frente acho q não é um operador mas sim o nome do objeto q foi criado com a ?, E o os : são cocatenados as informações

Comment: "i!" não é um operador, "i" é uma variável (que foi definida dentro do "for"), "!=" é o operador lógico "diferente de"; e "?:" é o operador ternário, é basicamente um "if" simplificado, antes do "?" é um teste lógico, se verdadeiro retorna o valor antes do ":", se falso, retorna o valor após o ":".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O operador `!=` significa diferente, ou compara se o `i` é diferente do `this.ultimo`. Exemplo:

```
//i = 5
//j = 4

boolean exemplo = (i == j) //false
boolean exemplo = (j != i) //true
```

o operador `?` é um if simplificado, por exemplo este if..

```
String exemplo = "";
if (i == 1){
  exemplo = "Igual a 1"
} else{
  exemplo = "Diferente de 1"
}
```

pode ser simplificado por:

```
String exemplo = (i == 1 ?   "Igual a 1" :  "Diferente de 1")
```

Ou seja o operador ? Testa a comparação, se for verdadeiro retorna o valor antes dos `:`, caso seja false, retorna depois..

Answer (score 3):

O nome deste tipo de condicional é ***If ternário*** ( [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) )

Simplificando :

```
? == if

:  == else
```

> **( ( i != this.ultimo) ? ", " : "")**;

Então se `i != this.ultimo` , concatene `“ , “` , senão concatene `“:”`